# Is it possible to import a MySQL 5.7.21 database into a MySQL 5.6.38 setup?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

I am running MAMP 4 with MySQL 5.6.38 and a team-mate of mine is running MAMP 5 with MySQL 5.7.21.

He has exported a database for me to use but I'm getting the following error when I import their database using Sequel Pro:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'json NOT NULL,
  `dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dateUpdated` datetime NOT N' at line 5
```

I am assuming the `MySQL server version` phrase is hinting that the mis-matched MYSQL versions is the issue here.

Upgrading to MAMP 5 may hurt other projects with other clients I have that all use my MAMP 4 install, but upgrading MySQL within MAMP 4 doesn't look simple.

Any advice on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: mysql 5.6 does not support json type. so just change json type to text text. everything should work

Comment: Going backwards is a lot harder than going forwards. What's the motivation here? Upgrading the older system is probably easier than reworking your schema.

Comment: Even at the time of posting this, MySQL 5.6.38 was horribly outdated. Why not update your setup, such that all colleagues use the same version?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't import any 5.7 database to a 5.6 instance.

Every version — of every brand of database — introduces new features. If the exported database from 5.7 uses some features that are not recognized by 5.6, you must either modify the export (as the comments above state), or else upgrade your own instance to match the version the export was made from.

Is it possible to design a database in 5.7 that uses only features that are also present in 5.6? Yes, of course.

But that doesn't seem to be the case for your team-mate's database.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this was the case.